# int32 and decimal convert

Tags: c#, class

I have a problem. In my class I defined product_ID as a int32 and product__price as a decimal. When I have to save data in database using textbox, i cant do it, it cannot convert it or something. please help me if you can. thank you.

```
public Int32 Product_ID { get; set; }
public String Product_name { get; set; }
public String Product_category { get; set; }
public Decimal Product_price { get; set; }
public string image_location { get; set; }
```

---

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Product_ID = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
product.Product_name = textBox2.Text;
product.Product_category = textBox3.Text;

product.Product_price = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
product.image_location = textBox5.Text;


Product.Save(product);
```

Comment: Have you tried `Decimal.Parse`?

Comment: How do you know there is a problem?  Perhaps there is an error message you could share with us?

Comment: `it cannot convert it or something`? What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: hmm.. input string was not in correct format

Answer (score 1):

Correct this line:

```
product.Product_price = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
```

to

```
product.Product_price = decimal.Parse(textBox4.Text);
```

Optimally you should check the content of the textbox first (if you don't already) so you are having correct comma, numbers only, try-catch and so forth.

Comment: Better yet, use a `NumericUpDown`.

Answer (score 1):

You must convert it to a decimal instead of a int sinse `product.Product_price` is of type decimal.. The types must always match.

```
product.Product_price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
```

or

```
product.Product_price = decimal.Parse(textBox4.Text);
```

**Update**
It's just a wild guess, but try this:

```
if(IsPostback)
{

    Product product = new Product();

    product.Product_ID = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    product.Product_name = textBox2.Text;
    product.Product_category = textBox3.Text;

    product.Product_price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox4.Text);
    product.image_location = textBox5.Text;


    Product.Save(product);

}
```

Comment: I corrected it but it doesnt even come to that line. Error is on first line. message: input string is not in a correct format :S

Comment: Maybe textBox3.Text is not the price? or maybe its empty (not filled out yet)

Comment: Try to debug (press f5) and when it stops at that line, place your cursor on textBox4.Text to see what is in it.